# Is it a good idea to separate domain admins and domain controller admins?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

Domain admins usually have access to all workstations in the domain, and the domain controllers too.

I see this as a security risk, because if a domain admin account gets compromised, the attacker gets access to the whole domain configuration (and not just workstations).

What would be better, would be to separate the two: a group that has access to all workstations, and a user (or group) that only has admin access on domain controllers.

Is it a good idea? Why is it not like this ?

Comment: Because by definition a _Domain_-Admin is an admin for the whole domain. If you want to fine tune this, do it. For example: we use an admin-account which is only admin on workstations and elevate permissions as needed in remote support. Then a domain-admin account which is barely ever used, and a "server"-admin account, which is used on servers and, just like the workstation account, is elevated if needed.

Comment: You're right. In fact, it exists in microsoft doc something like this: it is called ESAE (Enhanced security administrative environment): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/securing-privileged-access/securing-privileged-access-reference-material

Comment: I would actually let domain admins be admins of domain controllers...only.  Anybody who has full control of the domain controller essentially has full control of the domain anyway.  I agree with @Lenniey, server admins, workstation admins and domain admins - never the twain shall meet.  You should be more concerned about removing ANY access on workstations for the Domain Admins - that increases their liklihood of compromise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is it a good idea?` Yes

`Why is it not like this?`  In case you haven't noticed, Microsoft wasn't very good at security in the past, and some of the default configurations that aren't secure are still present. NetBIOS enabled on network adapters is another classic example.

In large forests with multiple domains, Domain Admins traditionally was not very useful if you wanted to use a single administrative account in one domain to managed multiple domains, due to Domain Admins is a Global Group.  So a Universal group would typically be created and added to the domain Administrators group, and administrative accounts added to the Universal Group so a single administrative account could have access to multiple domains if necessary. (Domain Admins gets nearly all privileges from membership in Administrators, and very few activities require Domain Admin membership).

With an ESAE and Microsoft Identity Manager (MIM), the limitations of Domain Admins in a multi-domain forest (or even multiple forests) no longer exist due to MIM can dynamically add shadow principals from the ESAE forest to Domain Admins even though Domain Admins is a Global Group. This access can be further limited to the amount of time an account has membership, so the only permanent member of Domain Admins would be the builtin Administrator account, which should only be used in emergencies.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/securing-privileged-access/securing-privileged-access-reference-material

Control Restrictions:

[image: Control Restrictions]

Logon Restrictions:

[image: Logon Restrictions]